# Python split string on +- character

Tags: python, split

I have the following string "158.8 ± 0.7" that gets pulled from someone else's html via beautifulsoup. I would like to split it into the number and error values as floats. I can't get the split function to split on the ± character though.

I've tried:

```
num, err = "158.8 ± 0.7".split('±')
num, err = "158.8 ± 0.7".split(u'U+00B1')
num, err = "158.8 ± 0.7".split('&plusmn;')
```

None of these work though. Any ideas?

I'm using Python 2.7

**Update**

I added `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as the first line of my code and now I get the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)`. Any further advice?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: When I paste your first line into the interpreter, it works in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Can someone explain why this question got down voted? I realize it works for other people, but that doesn't mean its not a problem for me.

Comment: @ericksonla, not sure why, I actually upvoted your question, since it did not work on my machine either. Does my soln below work for you?

Comment: @user308827 No, I get the same error I mentioned in the question edit whether I use split or re.split

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your file, do:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

This will allow non-ASCII characters to be dealt with.

and then use the re module for splitting,

```
import re
re.split('\W±', "158.8 ± 0.7")
```

Answer (score 0):

put

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

at start of the file to set unicode encoding. First example you posted will run fine.